# osCommerce mysql export to Excel

Tags: mysql, oscommerce

I need to export osCommerce product DB to Excel. Currently there are few tables:

```
- Products (list with all the products)
- Options (labels of the different options, e.g. size, color, etc)
- Options_Products (list will all the options for a given product, organised by product_id, option_id and value (e.g. red, 32, etc.))
```

I have to export every product on a single line, having one column for each option (e.g. color) and inside all the value (comma separated). If some option is not available for certain product, the field should be empty or null.

```
product_id
product_name
...
color (red, blue)
size (null)
some other option (23, 24, 24)
another option (null)
```

I'm having hard time creating this MySQL query and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the correct result from a query? Or exporting to Excel? Can we see the query you have tried so far?

Comment: It's the mysql query that I just cannot find the logic how to create it. I'm done with the part that get's me the products and some other information (what I wrote above is simplified) but I'm stuck to get all the options to be in a separate columns and the values inside to be comma separated.

Comment: You'll have to explain your table structure better. Maybe creating a sqlfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: There are a bunch of [add-ons](http://addons.oscommerce.com/category?search=export+orders+csv) for osCommerce for just this type of thing.  If it's not quite what you need, you can modify the code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will not be able to do this by a single query or your query will have some sub-queries.

I faced same problem and had to create a separate class. First it got an array (list) of products, and than, iterating products list, requested features list, including features names and values, for every product.

In some cases it's easier to make several methods in a class and get data "step-by-step" instead of trying to make a single complicated query.

Keep it simple, and good luck.